# TableView is not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, uitableview

I hope you guys help me in my code which is load data from a website. Let's start with the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad    
{
    [self loadDataFromUrl];        
}

-(void)loadDataFromUrl {

    NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://WebSite/PhpFiles/File.php"];

    NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myUrl];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                    JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in dataDictionary) {

      HotelObject *currenHotel = [[HotelObject alloc]initWithVTheIndex:                  
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"TheIndex"] timeLineVideoUserName:
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoUserName"] timeLineVideoDetails:
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoDetails"] timeLineVideoDate: 
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoDate"] timeLineVideoTime:
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoTime"] timeLineVideoLink:
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoLink"] timeLineVideoLikes:
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoLikes"] videoImage:
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"videoImage"] timeDeviceToken:
           [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"deviceToken"]];

           [self.objectHolderArray addObject:currenHotel];

    }    

}

-(NSMutableArray *)objectHolderArray{
    if(!_objectHolderArray) _objectHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return _objectHolderArray;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.objectHolderArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    HotelObject *currentHotel = [self.objectHolderArray
                                 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblID.text = currentHotel.vvTheIndex;
    cell.lblName.text = currentHotel.vvUserName;
    cell.lblCity.text = currentHotel.vvVideoDate;
    cell.lblAddress.text = currentHotel.vvVideoLikes;
    return cell;
}
```

The above code is loading data from a Url and fill the TableView and this step working fine. The app has another ViewController which is DetailsView, in DetailsView users can update some info. When the user goes back to the TableView nothing happened (I mean the data still the same and not updated). I have tried to call the loadDataFromurl from ViewDidAppear but it does not work.

I did add:

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

But still the same result.

Her is also my NSObject code:

```
-(instancetype)initWithVTheIndex:(NSString *)vTheIndex       
           timeLineVideoUserName:(NSString *)vUserName 
           timeLineVideoDetails:(NSString *)vVideoDetails
           timeLineVideoDate:(NSString *)vVideoDate 
           timeLineVideoTime:(NSString *)vVideoTime 
           timeLineVideoLink:(NSString *)vVideoLink 
           timeLineVideoLikes:(NSString *)vVideoLikes 
           videoImage:(NSString *)vVideoImage 
           timeDeviceToken:(NSString *)vDeviceToken {


    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.vvTheIndex = vTheIndex;
        self.vvUserName = vUserName;
        self.vvVideoDetails = vVideoDetails;
        self.vvVideoDate = vVideoDate;
        self.vvVideoTime = vVideoTime;
        self.vvVideoLink = vVideoLink;
        self.vvVideoLikes = vVideoLikes;
        self.vvVideoImage = vVideoImage;
        self.vvDeviceToken = vDeviceToken;

    }
    return self;
}
```

**My question is:** How can I update the TableView when moving from DetailsView or even when I pull to refresh.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly reloading the data source of your UITableView.

Assuming the remote URL is getting updated with the new data, and the issue is only reloading the TableView, make sure you add your `[self.tableView reloadData]` AFTER `loadDataFromUrl` has finished.

The `reloadData` method will always refresh the table's content, so either it's not being called at the right time or you are not updating `self.objectHolderArray`. (You can debug that by setting a breakpoint after calling `loadDataFromUrl` after the update.)

Comment: Thanks Meriw, I have got it

Answer (score 0):

on viewDidLoad lifecycle first [self.tableView reloadData] reload tableview then  another work.